# Is there a way to extract the first page of every PDF in a folder into one combined PDF?

Tags: macos, pdf, terminal, pdftk

I have a few hundred PDFs that I need to rip the first page off of and then throw into Tabula.

I thought this might work using a combination of PDFTK and Apple Terminal:

```
for file in desktop/test/*.pdf ; do pdftk *-page1.pdf cat output combined.pdf ; done
```

but I get the result:

> Error: Unable to find file.
>   Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
>      *-page1.pdf
>   Errors encountered.  No output created.
>   Done.  Input errors, so no output created.

It appears to be looking for one specific file and not all pdfs. Any ideas?

Comment: The tags [tag:macos] and [tag:batch-file] don't fit together.

Comment: I think it's `pdftk desktop/test/*.pdf cat 1 output combined.pdf`, but I don't have pdftk locally to test.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which files to take a page from with a handle. For instance, if you had two files, you would write `pdftk A=in1.pdf B=in2.pdf cat A1 B1 output out.pdf`. For many files, here is a script to generate the command line automatically.

```sh
handles=(); n=0; for i in *.pdf; do handles+=("`tr [0-9] [A-J] <<< $n`=$i"); ((n++)); done
pages=(); for i in `seq 0 $((n-1))`; do pages+=(`tr [0-9] [A-J] <<< $i`1); done
pdftk "${handles[@]}" cat ${pages[@]} output out.pdf
```

Comment: Ohhhh ok. That make sense but how do I point to the location of the folder?

Comment: Either run the script from the same directory your documents lie in, or replace `for i in *.pdf` with `for i in desktop/test/*.pdf`.